# Phonegap simulator

Tags: cordova, simulator, myeclipse

Trying to view the Phonegap simulator and it won't load but has error message that chrome or chromium browser is required. I am using Chrome. Have reinstalled Chrome. Still won't load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your Chrome or chromium installation is at a different location from what is expected. The expected location is mentioned in the error message and can be set in the preferences page at MyEclipse->Preferences...->MyEclipse/MobileTools/Mobile Web Simulator. Check that you have the correct location set up.